# Visual Studio 2012 Package Manager Console error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, package-managers

When trying to install anything with the Package Manager Console, I get this error:

```
Install-Package : The schema version of 'Microsoft.Bcl' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of      NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Moment.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: It's specifically telling you what's wrong. So...did you do what it said?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works now. I went to the site and had to uninstall and reinstall NuGet. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

I got this error when installing Nuget google calendar API 3.0, in Visual studio 2012.
Go to Tools -> Extension and updates -> there under updates you will find Nuget Package Manager. 
Try to update it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I've had a similar problem and going to the website linked in the error message simply redirects to https://www.nuget.org/. Trying to install NuGet from there, did not seem to work either.

I then tried to update NuGet via the other suggested approach (from Selvantharajah Roshanth)

> Go to Tools -> Extension and updates -> there under updates you will find Nuget Package Manager

There was no update option available there.

I then uninstalled it, went to the **Online** section of the "*Extensions and Updates*" and searched for Nuget. Installed the Nuget Package Manager from here which installed the newest and latest version. This resolved the error.