# Unable to install package Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc on Visual Studio 2010 express or upwards

Tags: google-api, nuget, nuget-package, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to install the NuGet package `Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc`. Upon doing so, I get the following error message:

*Install-Package : The schema version of 'Microsoft.Bcl' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to
 the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942*

I looked up this error message on Google and just one another guy reported such a problem in these two links ([Visual Studio 2012 Package Manager Console error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766168/visual-studio-2012-package-manager-console-error), http://servercoredump.com/question/21766168/visual-studio-2012-package-manager-console-error) and he had it fixed simply by uninstalling and re-installing NuGet.

I am scared to do that since I worry that NuGet may not download extensions for all the IDE's I have. I have from Visual Studio Express 2008 to 2013.

Have any of you encountered this message and do you know how to work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the BCL package is using a feature that is not supported by the outdated version of NuGet you seem to be using. You'll need to update the NuGet extension for Visual Studio.

1. Within Visual Studio, go to **Tools > Extensions and Updates...**
2. Select the **Updates** tab
3. Look for **NuGet Package Manager** and click the **Update** button.

Comment: if update is not available , reinstaling nuget worked for me.

Comment: I also had to uninstall and reinstall nuget to get rid of the error